# VMware Player 5.0.2: Hide full screen menu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to find a way to permanently hide the VMware menu bar when running in full screen mode. [For earlier versions](http://simplelight.wordpress.com/2008/08/04/removing-the-vmware-toolbar-in-fullscreen-mode/) one could add **pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar = “TRUE”** in the preferences file, but this doesn't seem to work in 5.0.2. As I'm using Ubuntu with the Unity interace it's a really annoying "feature" ...

- Host OS: Win7 x64
- VMware Player: 5.0.2
- virtual OS: Ubuntu 13.04 x64

Answer (score 1):

try "1" instead of "true"

> pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar = 1

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Considering that all other values in the preferences file are string based booleans ... I just doubt that will work.